# Is there a way to bring XAML enhancements of VS2013 into VS2012?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

There are new features in visual studio 2013 (currently preview edition) for XAML including:

- IntelliSense support for data binding and resources
- Go To Definition for navigating styles
- Code snippets

Is there a way to use these features in visual studio 2012 as a feature pack?

Is there any other 3rd party extension pack with similar capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using Resharper Plugin for years now http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/
Give it a try. Navigation to styles is possible by pressing Ctrl + Left Mouse button
Code snippets are supported and it improves IntelliSense anyway.